# why do I get bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program?

Tags: filesystems, mount

Check this:

```
root@dev:~# lsblk -f|grep sda 
sda         ext4              1.0        21ca0461-0e80-4468-b942-3735e9fd4945                 
root@dev:~# grep /db /etc/fstab
​UUID=21ca0461-0e80-4468-b942-3735e9fd4945 /db       ext4     errors=remount,ro   0 1
root@dev:~# mount /dev/sda /db 
root@dev:~# ls /db
lost+found  postgres-old  postgresql 
root@dev:~# umount /db 
root@dev:~# mount -a 
mount: /db: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. 
root@dev:~#
```

Why `mount -a` gives an error while simple `mount` doesn't?

Comment: Check `dmesg` for any relevant entries.

Comment: thanks, I have this in dmesg: `Unrecognized mount option "errors=remount,ro" or missing value` , looks like the correct is `errors=remount-ro`

Comment: I think this misleading message should be removed from `mount -a`